# Change of Variables Theorem with Inverted transformation

Tags: calculus

The change of variable theorem states

Given open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $G: U \rightarrow V$ be a one-to-one transformation of $C^1$ class whose derivative $DG(u)$ is invertible for all $u \in U$. Suppose that $T \subset U$ and $S \subset  V$ are measurable sets such that $G(T)=s$. If $f$ is an integrable function on $S$ then $f \circ G$ is integrable on T, and:

$\int_S f(x) d^nx = \int_T f(G(u)) |det DG(u)| d^nu$.

Is there a equivalent formulation of the above theorem but for the transformation in reverse?
In other words, if I am given $G^{-1}$, but $G$ is tedious to calculate, is there a formulation where I can proceed directly with $G^{-1}$? I vaguely recall something with $|det DG(u)|^{-1}$ in it.

Edit:

For example, if I want to use the substitution $(u,v) = G^{-1}(x,y) = (xy, x^2-y^2) $, and asked to integrate $\int_S x^3+y^3 dA$ where S is the region in the first quadrant bounded by $xy=1, xy=3, x^2-y^2 = 1, x^2-y^2=4$.

Comment: Assume you only have $G^{-1}$. Then just set $H := G^{-1}$ and apply your theorem to $H$. One can prove that $\lvert \det DH \rvert = \lvert \det DG \rvert^{-1}$. Note that $H$ is still one to one and $C^1$ by the [inverse function theorem](http://math.ucsd.edu/~nwallach/inverse[1].pdf).

Comment: I understand the determinant part, but wouldn't I still need an $x$ written in terms of $u$ to plug into $f$ on the R.H.S? Normally $x = G(u)$, but without an easy way to calculate $G$, how do I deal with $f(G(u))$?

Comment: As I said, we want to use $H := G^{-1}$ as "$G$". So if $S := H(T) = G^{-1}(T)$, then $\displaystyle \int_S f(x) ~\mathrm{d}^{n}x = \int_T f(G^{-1}(u)) \underbrace{\lvert \det DG(u) \rvert^{-1}}_{=\lvert \det H(u) \rvert} ~\mathrm{d}^n u$.

Comment: Just to illustrate my comment above, I've added an example in the question. $det H(x,y)$ would be $\frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}$. But how to I write $x^3+y^3$?

Comment: In other words, it doesn't seem like I am able to integrate by substitution, using $u$ and $v$ from $1$ to $3$ and $1$ to $4$ respectively, because I don't know what the expression is for $\int_S x^3+y^3 dA$ in terms of $u$ and $v$

Comment: Ok now I understand. i think that there is no formula for this, you have to find it out for yourself case by case. But maybe you try something easy like $x = \frac{cv}{ t(u, v)}$, $y = t(u, v)$,  for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and a function $t: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2-y^2 = u$.

Comment: Ok thanks for that info!